# An adaptation from Pablo Neruda's quote

Tags: gramática, ortografía

I'm taking a quote by Pablo Neruda and adapting it to something else.  Rewording it, changing the meaning too.  But I'd like to keep the Spanish --- if I could write it properly.  Can you help?

> Algún día en cualquier parte, en cualquier lugar, indefectiblemente
> hás de encontrar a ti mismo y solo de ti dependeres.  Que sea la
> más amarga de tus horas lo tus momento mejor.

**Update**.  I actually have seen a quote like that once in a picture in someone's office.  I don't quite recall the author, but I think it was a name such as M. de Comb.  Or something like that.  These are my words.  I recently realized this must have been an adaptation of Pablo Neruda's, but the adaptation seems so much better than the original.  I would love if I could find the name of the author of the adaptation.

Comment: As written, your version is full of mistakes. See my reply below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original quote seems to be:

> Algún día en cualquier parte, en cualquier lugar indefectiblemente te encontrarás a ti mismo, y ésa, sólo ésa, puede ser la más feliz o la más amarga de tus horas.
> <sub>(... and that may be your happiest or bitterest time.)</sub>

And I suspect you want to say the following:

> Algún día en cualquier parte, en cualquier lugar, indefectiblemente has de encontrarte a ti mismo y solo de ti dependerá que sea la más amarga de tus horas o tu mejor momento.
> <sub>(... and it will only be up to you that that is your bitterest or your best time.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you!  I'm choosing your answer because it seemed closer to the choice and order of words I was looking for.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Lo entiendo de este modo, ya que imprime más ritmo, mejor rima y sonoridad;

---

*Algún día en cualquier parte, en cualquier lugar,*

*indefectiblemente has de encontrarte a ti mismo*

*y solo de ti dependerá*

*que sea la más amarga de tus horas*

*o el mejor de los momentos*.

---